# How to disable category in magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento-2.1, category-products, navigation

I would like to disable category from navigation bar under some conditions like for certain customer groups I would like to show certain categories. Is there any way to do that and how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the category with this code.

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category_id = 'your_category_id';
$collection = $objectManager ->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category_id);
$collection->setData('is_active', 0);
$collection->save();

?>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to disable category in navigation without changing is_active status? I just want to hide category with some conditions like customer group.

Comment: One more question. Do you know which event will be evoked when top menu is rendering?

Comment: there are two events for category collection. 1. _load_before    2. _load_after

Comment: This code doesn't make a category disable. doesn't work for me

Comment: @VinitKumar Check in the admin if this code makes your category inactive or not.

Comment: @DineshYadav yes I have checked it doesn't make category disable

Answer (score 0):

First, create a custom attribute for categories like "show for customer [group]" with yes-no field then you can make use of plugin/interceptor in Magento to achieve this. In the plugin, check the current customer group and filter the categories that are enabled with the custom attribute you just created.

In this way, you can achieve your requirement. I think this is an ideal way to achieve this.